# Retrieve a cell from a budget file based on Today's Date

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with multiple worksheet tabs.
1 of the worksheet has 2 columns,Date and Target Sales

```
1. Date      Target Sales 
2. 1/1/2016  1,20,000
3. 2/1/2016  1,10,000
4. 3/1/2016  1,00,000
5. 4/1/2016  1,21,000
6. 5/1/2016  2,11,000
```

On my Main worksheet window I have a cell called 'Today's Target'
This cell needs to be pointed to the exact cell in the Target Sales column based on Todays date

For instance: If today is 2/1/2016
The expected result to be seen on the Today's Target cell should be 1,10,000

How can I achieve this in Excel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `VLOOKUP()`, as the following screen shot demonstrates:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tim,that was fast.What I am really looking at is on the Today cell I only have the word Today and no cell contents.I want to populate the cell today with 1,10,000.Vlookup will work great if I have a value under Today's Cell(D2).But I dont have a value,I want the cell to work dynically based on a function like today. Code would ideally be.1)Check today's date on the cell . 2) If today=2/1/2016 then fill cell d2 with 1,10,000

Comment: Just use the `NOW()` function if you want to get today's date, and enter that into cell `D2` in my example above.  Also note that column `A` must also be formatted as actual dates in order for the `VLOOKUP` to work correctly.

Comment: Tim,I modified my workbook to suggest what you said.and it works!Thanks